# PInvoke GetPackageId failing with error 122

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am trying to PInvoke this function (GetPackageId) from kernel32.dll:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446607(v=vs.85).aspx

I defined the structs and imports as follows:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PACKAGE_ID
    {
        uint reserved;
        uint processorArchitecture;
        PACKAGE_VERSION version;
        String name;
        String publisher;
        String resourceId;
        String publisherId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct PACKAGE_VERSION
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public UInt64 Version;
        [FieldOffset(0)] public ushort Revision;
        [FieldOffset(2)] public ushort Build;
        [FieldOffset(4)] public ushort Minor;
        [FieldOffset(6)] public ushort Major;
    }  

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetPackageId", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetPackageId(IntPtr hProcess,out uint bufferLength,out PACKAGE_ID pBuffer);
```

And calling it like this:

```
    PACKAGE_ID buffer = new PACKAGE_ID();
    result = GetPackageId(hProcess, out bufferLength, out buffer);
```

However I get a return value of 122 (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER). I am rather new to PInvoke and am not quite sure how to proceed from here. Do I need to initialize the strings before calling the function?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders If you don't mind I'm gonna borrow that comment for when I do those kind of edits myself.

Comment: No problem. It's a community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need to change the p/invoke:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern int GetPackageId(
    IntPtr hProcess,
    ref int bufferLength,
    IntPtr pBuffer
);
```

You call it once passing `0` for the length:

```
int len = 0;
int retval = GetPackageId(hProcess, ref len, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Then you need to check that `retval` equals `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`. If it does not then you have an error.

```
if (retval != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

Otherwise you can continue.

```
IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
retval = GetPackageId(hProcess, ref len, buffer);
```

Now you can check `retval` against `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

```
if (retval != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

And finally we can convert the buffer to a `PACKAGE_ID`.

```
PACKAGE_ID packageID = (PACKAGE_ID)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, 
    typeof(PACKAGE_ID));
```

Put it all together and it looks like this:

```
int len = 0;
int retval = GetPackageId(hProcess, ref len, IntPtr.Zero);
if (retval != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    throw new Win32Exception();
IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)len);
try
{
    retval = GetPackageId(hProcess, ref len, buffer);
    if (retval != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        throw new Win32Exception();
    PACKAGE_ID packageID = (PACKAGE_ID)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer,
        typeof(PACKAGE_ID));
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
}
```

---

From the comments it appears that we also need to make changes to the way the `PACKAGE_ID` struct is marshalled.

I suggest the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PACKAGE_ID
{
    uint reserved;
    uint processorArchitecture;
    PACKAGE_VERSION version;
    IntPtr name;
    IntPtr publisher;
    IntPtr resourceId;
    IntPtr publisherId;
}
```

followed by calls to `Marshal.PtrToStringUni` to convert the `IntPtr` string fields into C# strings. Naturally this conversion needs to happen before the call to `FreeHGlobal`.

My guess is that the API actually allocates the string buffers in the space beyond the end of `PACKAGE_ID`. Which is why you have to ask how much memory to allocate. I don't have Windows 8 at hand to test this hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks! It works all the way until the point you marshal the pointer to the structure. At that point it throws an exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException'

Comment: As a quick test, change the 4 string variables in PACKAGE_ID to be `IntPtr`. See if the problem is marshalling them. I can't test it out since I don't have Win 8.

Comment: I updated the answer so that I believe that it is now accurate.

Comment: As an aside the PACKAGE_VERSION structure is an union and struct layout has to be explicitly defined. Modified question to reflect this

Comment: OK. I didn't double check that. Do the 4 string pointers point to locations just beyond the end of the defined part of the struct as I hypothesised?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for GetPackageId it seems you should send the size of the buffer as argument when calling, i.e. bufferLength should be initialized with the size of the passed buffer.

On return the bufferLength will tell you the size of the returned buffer.

Or did misread the docs?

Comment: Seems you are right. I am now calling GetPackageId twice. The first time I get length and then call the function again with this length. But now I get an AccessViolationException-Attempted to read or write protected memory. I have a feeling its the way I have defined the [PACKAGE_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446775(v=vs.85).aspx) and [PACKAGE_VERSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446778(v=vs.85).aspx) structures but cant lay my finger on it.

Comment: Is the buffer you are passing the second time allocated then? To the size you are passing?

Comment: Sorry if I sound a bit dense but how exactly do I allocate it to that particular size? I am just doing this:    PACKAGE_ID buffer = new PACKAGE_ID();

Comment: That should probably do it. And if the size of the allocated buffer and the returned size differs you probably have some error in the definition.